# Can I add a cool Unicode up/down triangle to Bokeh HoverTool text?

Tags: bokeh

Can I add an icon from Unicode to a Bokeh HoverTool? I have some strange data which is 'bad' when it's positive and 'good' when it's negative in one graph and the opposite in another. I'd like to add Unicode characters in the HoverTool pop-up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you use the decimal representation of the character. If you wanted "Black Up-Pointing Triangle" (▲), you'd want to give your Hovertool the value `&#9650`. (I've had success doing this to get a delta symbol in hovertool values.)

If it were me, I might write some logic to add columns to the data source up front to have the up or down arrows easily available to the Hovertool.